# Way to make header span full width of page while using CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make my header span the full width of the page (no gaps on top and sides), but I have my header within a CSS grid, and so I'm having trouble making that happen.

I want my header to stay at the top of the page, which is part of the reason I've kept it in the grid. When I took it out and did position fixed, since it was taken out of flow, the stuff below ended up hidden behind it. At least when I keep it in grid and use position: sticky; it doesn't mess up the flow.

Is there a way to make my header span the full width of the page without taking it out of the grid?

```
header{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;

    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 1;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr, auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;

    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
}

#logo{
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
    width: 30%;
}

nav{
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
    align-self: end;
}
```

Comment: `position: sticky` doesn't play well with grids. If the header has a fixed height you can make it `position: fixed` and add a padding-top value on the body element equal to the header height so the content does not go below it.

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem you're having.

Comment: Use a **4** column grid?